# Writing numeric words with onkeypress

Tags: javascript, dom-events

How can I write numeric numbers into an input field by pressing a button?

Suppose I have a button:

```
<input type="button" value="1">
```

Then I want, that when numeric pad button <kbd>1</kbd> is pressed it adds numeric words just like Windows Calculator.

Comment: What do you mean by "numeric word"? Which input field do you want to fill?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are asking, but this code will add numbers to an input box (using jQuery).

HTML

```
<input id="data" type="text" />
<br />
<br />
<input type="button" value="1" />
<input type="button" value="2" />
<input type="button" value="3" /><br />
<input type="button" value="4" />
<input type="button" value="5" />
<input type="button" value="6" /><br />
<input type="button" value="7" />
<input type="button" value="8" />
<input type="button" value="9" />
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 $(':button').click(function(){
  $('#data').val( $('#data').val() + $(this).val() );
 })
})
```